# how to iterate DOM in JQuery

Tags: jquery

following is the HTML

```
<div id="serverList" class="content">
    <div class="boxtitle">
    </div>
    <div id='serverInfo1' class="formEl_b">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Server #1</legend>
            <div class="section">
                <label>
                    Server Description<small>Linux</small></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="serverDescription" class="serverDescription medium" /><span class="f_help"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <label>
                    Server HostName<small>SRV_FR_TERT</small></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="serverHostName" class="serverHostName medium" /><span class="f_help"></span></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id='serverInfo2' class="formEl_b">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Server #2</legend>
            <div class="section">
                <label>
                    Server Description<small>Windows 2003</small></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="serverDescription" class="serverDescription medium" /><span class="f_help"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <label>
                    Server HostName<small>SRV_EQ_SFGT</small></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="serverHostName" class="serverHostName medium" /><span class="f_help"></span></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id='serverInfo3' class="formEl_b">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Server #3</legend>
            <div class="section">
                <label>
                    Server Description<small>iOS</small></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="serverDescription" class="serverDescription medium" /><span class="f_help"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <label>
                    Server HostName<small>SRV_WR_RQRT</small></label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="serverHostName" class="serverHostName medium" /><span class="f_help"></span></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to iterate the above html using JQuery and to print `description` and `hostname` for every server

```
$("#serverList").children(".formEl_b").each(function () {

      // this is what i am trying to get with no success:
      var description = $(".formEl_b .serverDescription").val();
      var hostname = $(".formEl_b .serverHostName").val();

      alert(description);
      alert(hostname);

});
```

The problem that i'm having is that it always prints the first `description` and `hostname` even that there are 3 items of that kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector

```
$(".formEl_b .serverDescription")
```

Is finding all elements with the class `.serverDescription` that appear anywhere in the DOM as a descendant of `.formEl_b`, but since you are already looping the parent elements you can use something like this :

```
$("#serverList").children(".formEl_b").each(function () {
      var description = $(this).find(".serverDescription").val();
      var hostname = $(this).find(".serverHostName").val();
      alert(description);
      alert(hostname);
});
```

Replaces your selectors with [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to just search the descendants of the current element within the `each` loop

`find()` is [marginally faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel) than using a selector with context (ie `$(".serverDescription", this)`)

Answer (score 1):

Inside `.each()`, use `this` to refer to the element current under iteration.

So:

```
$("#serverList").children(".formEl_b").each(function () {

      var description = $(".serverDescription", this).val();
      var hostname = $(".serverHostName", this).val();

      alert(description);
      alert(hostname);

});
```

Or equivalently:

```
      var description = $(this).find(".serverDescription").val();
```

Comment: @ManseUK JQuery docs say "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span')." Hence I didn't expect the performance to be perceivably different, thanks for the benchmark!